# Unable to start a bounty using Opera Mini

Tags: bug, status-declined, bounties, opera-mini

I am unable to start a bounty using Opera Mini, despite the fact that pretty much all other JS/AJAX functions work.

When I choose to start one, the mini-wizard appears, as it should, but I cannot select "Next". It simply 'refreshes' the page with the mini-wizard still in place. I also cannot select "cancel", or the "x" at the top-right of the mini-wizard.

Comment: Can you see client side errors?

Comment: There are no errors - it simply does a quick refresh (or redraw, as the server does not make any changes to the page when I click "Next").

Comment: Confirmed - however I'm struggling to understand how Opera expects us to debug any problem on this brower: there is no real javascript console, and javascript is run on a server... http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-and-javascript/

Comment: Weird indeed - it's just interesting how other JS actions work, but this one does not. I know that, when I need to add a comment with Mini, I have to press "Add Comment" twice, but that's natural as you have scripts that count the characters left. That, I can understand. But this, there;s just something wrong. It's just not registering a thing. and I'm surprised they don't have a debugging facility. I, too, have had problems with my apps on Mini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment we don't support Opera mini.

Reason: a combination of amount of work required and amount of visitors using the browser.

Comment: [Relevant FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/179372)

Comment: The FAQ entry doesn't explain why though, it just links to this answer. Wasn't it because Opera Mini's proxy doesn't support gzipping? Wasn't there a Meta answer from Jeff to that effect?