# Delete button not working in Opera Mini

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web, vote-to-delete, opera-mini

When I log in through my Nokia Classic device, a delete button appears at the bottom of my answers. But when I click the delete button, the page simply reloads instead of deleting my answer. Is this a bug?

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: @AshRj Nokia Classic :)

Comment: as explained in the answer, we don't support opera mini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it appears that classic Nokia comes with [Nokia Browser for Symbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Browser_for_S60) as the default browser.

Stack Exchange sites are not supporting all existing browsers. List of supported (and explicitly unsupported) browsers can be found here: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/152859)

Try installing standard mobile browser like Chrome or Firefox and everything should work fine.

Comment: Nope.. I am using opera mini in my mobile device instead of Nokia Browser.

Comment: You should have mentioned this in your post, it's very important information...

Comment: Surely http://example.com can support all existing browsers. Including Mosaic.

Comment: @Veekay Opera Mini is [explicitly unsupported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177509/152859). I fear you'll have to use other, more standard, browser to use Stack Overflow properly.

Comment: @Manishearth good point, edited.

Comment: ok.. I got it.. thanks

Comment: @Veekay: Opera mini wreaks havoc with many elements on a page -- in its efforts to make the page more lightweight it cuts off many features. Opera Mini is best used for reading static websites, not for heavy interaction.

Comment: @Manishearth this makes sense, after all it's "mini" so it justifies its name! ;-)