# Getting 404 error when trying to flag question or answer

Tags: support, flags, stackexchange.com

I am unable to flag any question or answer on Stackoverflow mobile website. In flag pop-up, when i click '  it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate' radio button, it throughs error 404 instead of displaying sub-menu options to flag. This is happening from last two days, someone pls help!
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce here. What browser you use? What page it try to load? (You can see it in a network tab of the browser's dev tools)

Comment: I can flag questions here and all other websites of stackexchange network except stackoverflow. I use opera mobile for android.

Comment: If it's Opera Mini then [it's not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177509/152859).

Comment: Well its opera `mobile`.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and having same problem in "It doesn't belong here" option also

Comment: Using FF 23.0.1 on windows 7 I get the following:
GET http://stackoverflow.com/flags/questions/5378913/close/popup?_=1377550677974 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 22ms]

Comment: Marking as dupe of newer question as it got better description and screenshots.