# Welcome <username>, you have been logged in, click here to refresh

Tags: support, live-refresh

I logged in to stackoverflow from my ericsson mobile through OperaMini-6.1 browser. And, then I wanted to visit my GreatOutdoors profile. I clicked the link, and saw the pop-up stated as the title of this question. And, then I kept on refreshing, the page didn't appear. Tried it with UCBrowser-8.3, it worked. Any issue here with OperaMini-6.1?

Comment: What really should happen is make it so you don't need to refresh. It just logs you in with the AJAX, then using AJAX, set the necessary JS variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Opera Mini is explicitly unsupported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177352/unable-to-start-a-bounty-using-opera-mini/177509#177509), so don't expect it to work correctly.

You can check which browsers are officially supported and other pertinent information in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/191706).

Comment: @WedaPashi may I ask what mobile device you use?