# "Page not found" on my Nokia Windows Mobile device after submitting or asking a question.... is there any app for Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange?

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web

I have submitted one question by using my mobile. First of all, tags autocomplete is not working there, but after loading, it will show the tags after selecting one tag. While I am posting the question, it is showing "Page not found". What is happening?

I tried it 2-3 times, and the same thing happened.

I am using [Opera Mini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini) on my mobile (Nokia)... Please suggest me otherwise. Do I have to go my desk every time and ask a question from my PC?

Is Stack Overflow not applicable for a mobile device browser?

Is there any application available for Stack Overflow?

Comment: As for official app where you can post questions there's only for android at the moment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200/152859

Comment: If you want... ;-)

Comment: As noted by others, we do not support Opera-mini.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Stack Overflow not applicable for a mobile device browser?
>
> I am using Opera Mini on my mobile

Stack Overflow is available for mobile browsers, but you are not using one of the [supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/152515), so strange behaviour should be expected. In fact, Opera Mini is [explicitly unsupported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177509/152515). If you're not using one of those browsers, you're sort of on your own - you're using a browser that isn't popular enough to merit the staff supporting it.

Try the default Android browser, or the Safari browser if you're using iOS.

Since you're on a Windows 8 Nokia phone, you could try the IE mobile browser - that one isn't officially supported, but at least it's not explicitly unsupported! Unfortunately, this is one of the browsers that isn't popular enough to merit the staff supporting it.

> Is there any application available for Stack Overflow?

If you have an Android phone, you can try the [Android App alpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app) - but it's an alpha, and not fully functional.

You should stick to using your desktop browser for SE sites.

Comment: hi I am using Nokia mobile

Comment: It is really strange for me your supported browsers list I saw there is opera....!!

Comment: Opera Mini is not Opera.

Comment: ok for nokia mobile what should I do? any app available for this? or any other windows mobile browser?

Comment: Just saying the brand of the phone won't help with suggestions. Nokia phones have been around for 15-odd years. What is the Operating System on it? Is it a Windows 8 OS? Symbian? Android?

Comment: windows ....os..is there any browser that will solve it for windows mobile? I am trying it on firefox....let me check

Comment: @RajarshiDas There are no offically supported browsers for a Windows 8 Nokia phone, but you could at least try the IE browser.

Comment: I had tried even IE same  loading and loading auto complete broken...and then page not found ..then I used opera but ....again same

Comment: @RajarshiDas Then you are on your own. The Android and iOS Safari browsers are the only supported mobile browsers for Stack Exchange. That said, I use an Android browser that _isn't_ the default, so maybe there's a browser available for Windows 8 - one other than Opera Mini - that will work with SO.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Chrome can run on any device. Give it a try.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd a big thank you ...chrome solve my issue