# Elements overlapping and white space issues in the mobile site with Opera mini

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web, opera-mini

I've noticed that if you browse a SE site from a phone, there is a bit overlapping on the "unanswered" and "ask" link, making it difficult to click. Can the SE site designer/s take this in consideration and add some margin/padding? I think that a white space of 3-4px would suffice, so it looks even less cluttered.

The other thing is that there are also some issues with the white space. As many of you who design website know, white space in web designing and absolutely in mobile designing, is vital to the user experience/perception.

No white space give you the feeling of "mental claustrophobia" and that's not good.
One place where no white space is involved are the tags for example. They are stacked against each other and when they are shown below the title, there is no space between the two.

Was this done by fast/distract designing or discarded willingly?

I'm thinking the real problem could be Opera mini.

This happens on a Nokia
700 and browser Opera mini 7.1.32444

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you can provide phone/os and browser info. It's looking perfect on iOS/Safari.

Comment: Oh yes you're right! This is on a Nokia 700 and browser Opera mini 7.1.32444

Comment: @slowbanned [Opera Mini is not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177509/152859). Use Chrome or Firefox instead, both should support any mobile device as far as I know. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard you would be wrong. Opera is basically the only modern option, which is why I dont browse SE with my phone (same OS as OP's phone)

Comment: @3ventic oh, that's too bad then. But I saw Opera is supported so if using it and still seeing broken things it's valid to report and ask for a fix.

Comment: Looks fine in full opera mobile