# Captcha Challenge without a Captcha

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, captcha, opera-mini

I am using Stack Exchange and its sites through my basic mobile Nokia C1 using Opera Mini 4.5.

I was prompted frequently to prove that I am a Human and not a Robot before providing an answer for a question which was not answered very quickly. It even happens for a question which was asked 1 hour ago.

The problem is, there is no Captcha shown to prove, only a hyperlink for a Captcha which link to Wiki and a Text box to type that Captcha.

Now, how can I prove I am Human without knowing the Captcha?

But I am able to answer after refreshing that page more than 2, 3 times. Is that any bug or anything else?

Comment: we've recently started using [the new no captcha recaptcha](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwslDn3ImM0). can you provide more details about what exactly you're seeing (screenshot, you get bonus points for drawing freehand red circles)?

Comment: @モサ nice new name! Anyway, as far as I can tell, [Opera Mini is not supported by Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177509/152859), unless something has changed?