# Strange issue on new stackexchange style sheet

Tags: bug, status-declined

I am facing a very strange issue using stackexchange sites on my mobile device. I use Opera mini V4 and V6  browsers.

The problem I am facing is this: When I click on any link in question or anywhere on the site, it loads the same page on first click, on second click it expands the webpage, I mean the page becomes wide 50 px more for example. On third click it goes to a wrong link, If I am on a recent question page, I try to open a question, click on the title, it opens the tag instead.

I have been facing this problem since Stackexchange launched a new stylesheet for profiles. I had no such problem on the old style of SE.

Can SE please understand my problem and solve it for opera mobile devices?

Comment: Gif maybe? Please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need):

> **Opera Mobile**
>
> - Stack Overflow appears to function properly in 12.0.1
> - **Explicitly unsupported: Opera Mini ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177509/152859))**

And from [Unable to start a bounty using Opera Mini](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177352/unable-to-start-a-bounty-using-opera-mini):

> Unfortunately at the moment we don't support Opera mini.
>
> Reason: a combination of amount of work required and amount of
>   visitors using the browser.