# Japanese version of Stack Overflow not working in Opera Mini browser

Tags: bug, opera-mini

I am unable to use the Japanese version of Stack Overflow.

I have an account on [here](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9603/starkeen).

The problem I am facing is this: Whenever I try to upvote/downvote or post questions/answers, I get an error:

> **Bad request-invalid url**
>
> Http 400 error: the requested url is invalid

[ScrollView内にあるImageViewをタップした時の座標値を取得したい（Swift2.1）](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20219/scrollview%E5%86%85%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%8Bimageview%E3%82%92%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E5%BA%A7%E6%A8%99%E5%80%A4%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-swift2-1)

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce, was able to upvote that question now. What browser/OS? Do you see errors in your console?

Comment: I am on opera mini 6 OS Java

Comment: Opera Mini is not supported. Use a common browser instead.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Does this version of SO work on  java OS devices?

Comment: If you'll have a standard browser like Chrome, the OS should not matter, as the browser should do all the hard work. (Mainly JavaScript rendering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need):

> **Opera Mobile**
>
> - Stack Overflow appears to function properly in 12.0.1
> - **Explicitly unsupported: Opera Mini ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177509/152859))**

And from [Unable to start a bounty using Opera Mini](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177352/unable-to-start-a-bounty-using-opera-mini):

> Unfortunately at the moment we don't support Opera mini.
>
> Reason: a combination of amount of work required and amount of
>   visitors using the browser.